# run the same script for multiple files, scripts requires 2 input files

Tags: shell-script, command-line, parallelism

I have a folder containing 500 genotype files, like this:

```
xaa.txt
xab.txt
xac.txt
xad.txt
```

I want to run a script for each genotype file separately at the same file; I know this question has been answered before, BUT, my script requires "2" input file format (the first file is my genotype files which are 500 files , second file is a single individual-population file. My script also require output files for every genotype.file.

for a single genotype file I was easily using

```
perl ./my_script.pl  my_geno_file.tab.table  good_individuals.txt  results.out.tab.table
```

where my_geno_file.tab.table is the first file(I have now 500 geno_files),good_individuals.txt is the second input file and results.out.tab.table is the third input file which should be empty.. 
could you please help me how can I run this script at the same time for all 500 files?

Answer (score 1):

You can go for `xargs`. First, feed it with the files through a pipe on the stdin, and then use the arguments with an executable, while keeping control of the parallelism by setting the maximum number of processes to be used.

```
printf "%s\0" _the_right_dir_/* | xargs -0 -I@ -P500 ./my_script.pl @ file_2 @file_3
```

`-0` tells `xargs` that the input is NUL-separated.

`-I@` defines the substitution symbol. In the effect the second `@` on the right side of the pipe (`|`) is substituted with a file name. Then it appears once more in `@file_3` to demonstate you can use `@` once more in the same command. Here to produce the output file name.

`-P500` stands for a maximum of 500 processes to be run at the same time.

Finally, `printf "%s\0" _the_right_dir_/*` lists the directory files separating them with NULs. Then `xargs` takes them one by one and uses them as arguments to `./my_script.pl`.

Comment: @tomos, thanks. I have editted my question a bit now. what a bout file 1 which are my genotype files?